# How to select one plot from coplot(), or how to plot a specific subset

Tags: r, plot, subset

I am trying to use `coplot` like this:

`coplot(lat ~ long | depth, data = quakes)`

Which produce this" [image: This is a scatter plot for each level of depth]

However, this will give a plot for each level of conditioning variable. I would like to get a whole scatter plot without showing the levels of variables. For example similar to this:

[image]

How can I customize this? any help please?

Comment: It is unclear what you want. Customize what, in what way?

Comment: I want to have a single plot shows the dependence between X and y condition on X.

Comment: Do you just want to plot a subset? `plot(quakes[quakes$lat > -25 ,2:1])`

Comment: @AkselA thank you so much for your great help. the `coplot` give me a matrix of plot based on the values of the given variable. I just want to have one single plot not a matrix. That is I would like ` coplot(lat ~ long | depth, data = quakes)` to give me  a single plot.

Comment: Wouldn't that also just be the scatterplot of a subset? `plot(quakes[quakes$depth > 400 ,2:1])`

Comment: Thanks a gain for your help. Could you please just let me know what does `2:1` mean?

Comment: `2:1` creates the integer sequence starting with 2 and ending with 1. It's a slightly shorter way of writing `c(2, 1)`. The final result is that the second and first columns are selected, in that order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears like what you really want is to plot a subset. How you subset data varies a bit depending on what form it is in (vector, matrix, dataframe, list; numeric, logical, character). This here will work with a numeric dataframe like `data(quake)`.

First of all you'll need to understand the function of `[]`. If you search the help for `Extract` you'll find info on it and its siblings. `[]` is used to extract elements from vectors, matrices, dataframes and arrays of any dimension, based on indices of each dimension, with each dimension separated by a comma.

Say you have a vector `vec <- c(1, 3, 2, 6, 4)`. A vector only have one dimension so you don't have to worry about which dimension you are addressing. `vec[3]` will return `2`, the value at place, or index, 3 in the vector, the third element from the left. `vec[5]` will return the fifth element: `4`, while `vec[c(2, 1, 4)]` will return the second, first and fourth element, in that order.

When dealing with matrices and dataframes we are dealing with two dimensions, commonly referred to as rows and columns. When using `[]` the dimensions will always be separated like this: `[rows, columns]`. Lets create a matrix.

```
mat <- matrix(c(9, 8, 7
                6, 5, 4
                3, 2, 1), nrow=3, byrow=TRUE)
mat
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    9    8    7
# [2,]    6    5    4
# [3,]    3    2    1
```

Along the top and bottom there are `[]`'s with numbers in them referring to the index of each dimension. You'll also notice that along the side the number is in front of a comma, signifying row, while along the top the number stand after the comma, signifying column.

So what happens if I call `mat[3, ]` or `mat[, 2]`? Well I get every element in that respective row or column.
What about if we want to extract the `4` in the above matrix? Well its row is nr 2, and its column is nr 3, so could it simply be `mat[2, 3]`? Why yes, it is!
We're nearly there now, only other thing to show is that we can reference rows and columns by name, not just by index. The above matrix doesn't have any dimension names, so we'll have to add them.

```
rownames(mat) <- c("r1", "r2", "r3")
colnames(mat) <- c("c1", "c2", "c3")
mat
#    c1 c2 c3
# r1  9  8  7
# r2  6  5  4
# r3  3  2  1
```

Now `mat[,"c2"]` will return the column called `c2`, and `mat["r1"]` the row called `r1`.

Onto `quakes`.
Say we want to plot all earthquakes with a focus deeper than 400 km.

One straight forward way of extracting that subset could be

```
quakes.sub <- quakes[quakes[,"depth"] > 400, c("long", "lat")]
```

The only new thing here is `>`, which in this instance asks: "are the values in `quakes[,"depth"]` larger than 400?". For every yes a `TRUE` is returned, and for every no a `FALSE`. Only columns returning `TRUE` will be included in the subset.

To plot the subset you only have to

```
plot(quakes.sub)
```

[image]

This is only the start of course. You can use `with()` to avoid having to type `quakes` several times, using `which()` will deal with `NA`'s more gracefully, and conditions (`<`, `>`, `==`) can be stacked using logical operators (not: `!`, and: `&`, or: `|`), allowing for more advanced subsetting rules.

```
rows <- with(quakes, which(depth < 400 &
                           depth > 100 &
                             mag > 4.3 &
                        stations > 20))
quakes.sub <- quakes[rows, c("long", "lat")]

plot(quakes.sub)
```

[image]